# ASP.NET MVC SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to follow this page http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx and this is what I have in global.asax,

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MemberRoute",                       // routeName
            "member/{userId}/{pseudoName}", // url
            new
            {                           // url defaults
                controller = "Member",
                action = "Index",
                userId = 0,
                pseudoName = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new
            {                          // url constraints
                userId = @"\d+" // must match url {userId}
            }
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

MemberController,

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string pseudoName)
    {
        User user;
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        user = unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetById(id);

        var expectedName = user.PseudoName.ToSeoUrl();
        var actualName = (pseudoName ?? "").ToLower();

        // permanently redirect to the correct URL
        if (expectedName != actualName)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Member", new { id = user.UserId, pseudoName = expectedName });
        return View(user);
    }
```

This is returned from the Login action from the AccountController,

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Member", new { id = user.UserId, pseudoName = user.PseudoName });
```

When the redirect takes place, the Url ends up looking like http://site.com/Member/1?pseudoName=CEO

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `RedirectToRoute("Member", new { id = user.UserId, pseudoName = user.PseudoName })`. Look up `RedirectToRoute`.

Comment: I get the error "A route named 'Member' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name"

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you're using `MapRoute` over `MapHttpRoute`, so you want to call it using `RedirectToRoute` or (in the markup) `@Html.RouteLink`.

So, to make it work in your above code, instead of redirecting to an action, then specifying the parameters, use the following:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Member", new {
  userId = user.Id, // note i use userId as it's in the route's url
  pseudoName = user.pseudoName
});
```

Also, a fix in your route would go as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Member",                       // routeName
  "member/{userId}/{pseudoName}", // url
  new {                           // url defaults
    controller = "Member",
    action = "Index",
    userId = 0,
    pseudoName = UrlParameter.Optional
  },
  new {                          // url constraints
    userId = @"\d+"              // must match url {userId}
  }
);
```

Comment: Copied this exactly and I still get the error... A route named 'Member' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name

Comment: Where do you have a reference to `{name}`? Maybe another route with `{name}` in its url?

Comment: I don't have any other routes defined.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not doing this right, I don't really know much at all about route mapping.

Comment: @user: How many other routes are mapped? Can you post what you have in your question with an update?

Comment: Updated with all the code in global.asax I just changed the route name from "Member" to "MemberRoute" and also changed it in the RedirectToRoute but still the same error.